# как сохранять вложения писем из Outlook - VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

как сохранять вложения писем из Outlook и сделать ссылку в бд аксес на это вложение, пересмотрел довольно много примеров, однако так и не понял методику приведите пример. Пробовал так сохранять вложение, но не работает.

```
Sub ListInbox()
Dim b As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim c() As String
DestFolder = "C:\Users\Alecs\Desktop\ghbkj;tybz gbctv\"
Set myFolder = 
Outlook.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set myAttachment = myFolder.Items
For Each mi In myFolder.Items.Restrict("[Unread]=TRUE")
If mi.Subject = "Инвентаризация" Then
b = mi.Body
c = Split(b, "<p>")
q = c(0)
IF meAttachment.count > 0 THEN
For i = 1 To Item.Attachments.Count
  myAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile DestFolder & 
Item.Attachments.Item(i).DisplayName
Next i
END IF
MsgBox q
Call dbaseInv
```